# What are the modern marvels in Physics that seem crazy but true?

Tags: soft-question

What are the modern marvels in Physics which are crazy but true? Ideas which are ridiculed and dismissed in the beginning but passed the test of time?

Comment: Suggested an edit that might save the question, also [check my comment on Martin's answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/craziest-ideas-in-physics-which-are-true/6799#comment-17207) for more insight. Still, it might get too specific in time OR turn into a long list of answers.

Comment: Some nonconstructive comments removed. It appear the OP is back but has lost control of the account that posted this question. If so, please flag for a moderator and tell us the UserID of you new account so that they can be merged.

Answer (score 2):

Just about all of them?

From the Earth going around the sun through to relativity and quantum mechanics

Comment: Please note that most of your answer is invalidated by the last sentence of the question. But well, then the question is where to draw the line and then it gets to be about a specific moment or time or would still result in a list post. I think that he is not clear in his wordings, he is looking at crazy things that the begginner to average Physician doesn't know about...

Comment: I think relativity and QM have stood the test of time, for nearly 100years they have stood up against every experiment and have provided testable predictions - you can't ask for more

Comment: That's not what my comment is about, it's about "all of them" and the "earth going around the sun". ;-)

Comment: @TomWij--copernicus didn't publish until after his death precisely becuase he feared persecution for his argument.  Galileo was put under house arrest.  How on Earth is that not being 'ridiculed' for your belief?

Comment: Bruno got really burned up about it! Although to be fair both Galileo and Bruno really ran into power politics rather than simple religion vs science

Answer (score 1):

Einstiens theory of relativity was at first considered ridiculous now it is  widely accepted

Comment: Any references for this?

Comment: @Marek: Well, the reason his Nobel Prize was for the photoelectric effect was because Special Relativity was still considered too controversial at the time.

Comment: @Jerry: controversial perhaps (although I'd like to see a reference for this too) but ridiculous?

Comment: Time changes when you are moving! Thats not ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

Relativity and Quantum Theory. That whole division of the waters thing, of the infinite and infinitesimal, leaving our everyday world of beer and sandwiches in the middle. But I still don't understand mass, or gravity or momentum.
Cataclysm Theory and Continental Drift. Loads of stuff.
Some of the replies seem a bit shirty, but I'm glad to have found this blog. After all, we have a vicar in every parish and most of them willing to discuss theology; its high time science/scepticism offered the same. I promise not to ask about flying saucers or quantum wormholes, well maybe quantum wormholes...